# got an error while using @if in razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've got an error when I tried to use if clause in razor like this:

Unexpected "if" keyword after "@" character.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
@if (item.Country != "No Country")
{
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(item.CountryWithCount, "IndexByProv", "EventInfo", new { country = item.Country }, null)</li>
```

Why I got this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You dont need `@`  because you are already inside a code block.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
  if (item.Country != "No Country")
  {
    <li>something</li>
  }
}
```

Comment: Concur +1. As a side note, inside of a code block where you are using code which is not c# or a razor call, then it can be pertinent to use `@:` to indicate a line of text and escape the razor engine.